# How to combine two different tables in the following way?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, dataset

Consider the following two grids:

```
grid1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}];
grid2 = Flatten[Thread[{#[[1]], #[[2]], Range[3]}] & /@ grid1, 1];
```

Therefore, `grid2` is `grid1` but with additional coordinate.

Next, consider the tables of values of two functions `func1`, `func2` on `grid1`, `grid2`:

```
func1[x_,y_]=Exp[-x]*Cos[y];
func2[x_,y_,z_]=Exp[-x^2]Sin[y]/z;
vals1 = Join[grid1, {func1[#[[1]],#[[2]]]} & /@ grid1, 2];
vals2 = Join[grid2, {func2[#[[1]],#[[2]],#[[3]]]} & /@ grid2, 
   2];
```

I want to obtain the table

```
table=Join[grid2,{func1[#[[1]],#[[2]]]*func2[#[[1]],#[[2]],#[[3]]]}&/@grid2,2]
```

assuming that I do not know `func1`, `func2`, i.e., having **pre-computed** `vals1`, `vals2`.

Could you please tell me how to do this quickly (in reality, `vals1`, `vals2` are large multi-dimensional datasets)?

Comment: `Join[grid2, List /@ Flatten[vals1[[All, -1]] Partition[vals2[[All, -1]], 3]], 2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Join[grid2, 
 List /@ Flatten[vals1[[All, -1]] Partition[vals2[[All, -1]], 3]], 2]
```

[image]

```
% == table
```

> True